# Spanner setAllowPartialRead(true) usage and purpose

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

from offical code snippet example of Spanner Java Client :
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/HEAD/spanner/spring-data/src/main/java/com/example/spanner/SpannerTemplateSample.java

I can see the usage of
new SpannerQueryOptions().setAllowPartialRead(true)):

```
@Component
public class SpannerTemplateSample {

  @Autowired
  SpannerTemplate spannerTemplate;

  public void runTemplateExample(Singer singer) {
    // Delete all of the rows in the Singer table.
    this.spannerTemplate.delete(Singer.class, KeySet.all());

    // Insert a singer into the Singers table.
    this.spannerTemplate.insert(singer);

    // Read all of the singers in the Singers table.
    List<Singer> allSingers = this.spannerTemplate
        .query(Singer.class, Statement.of("SELECT * FROM Singers"),
                new SpannerQueryOptions().setAllowPartialRead(true));
  }

}
```

I didn't find any explanation on it. Anyone can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gcp/docs/1.1.0.M1/reference/html/_spring_data_cloud_spanner.html):

Partial read is only possible when using Queries. In case the rows returned by query have fewer columns than the entity that it will be mapped to, Spring Data will map the returned columns and leave the rest as they of the columns are.

Comment: Nice catch! How is your way of searching the documentation !!!